# рендер значения в шаблон из json объекта python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, json, flask

У меня есть метод `profile`и шаблон profile.html.

В profile.html есть выпадающий список из мейлов пользователей. Когда я выбираю один из них, появляется модальное окно с этим мейлом, и я могу отправить ему сообщение. Я получаю этот мейл туда через AJAX.

Проблема в том, что `born_date` и `phone_number` этого пользователя, которые я получаю из базы данных, не отображаются в шаблоне, и я не вижу их в модальном окне. В чем может быть проблема?

```
def str_value_to_list(text: str):
    *_, email_json = re.findall(r'[^ \',()]+', text)
    return email_json
```

`#метод profile страницы`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users.data WHERE description = 'doctor'")
        account = cur.fetchall()
        description = account
        countries = ['USA','France','Italy','Spain','Australia','New Zealand']
        return render_template(
            'profile.html', 
            id = session['id'], 
            email = session['email'],
            firstname = session['firstname'], 
            description = description, 
            countries = countries
        )
```

`#метод для получения даты и номера в модальном окне`

```
@app.route('/api/get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Holy Shit!')
        data = request.json
        print(str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        born = account[0]
        num = account[1]
        print(born)
        print(num)
        return jsonify({
            'born': born, 
            'num': num,
        })
```

`#метод отправки сообещние на почту юзеру`

```
@app.route('/api/send_msg', methods=['POST'])
def send_msg():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.json('sel')
        print(docs)

        for doc in docs:
            print(type(doc))
            res = doc.split()
        print(res[2].replace("'","")[:-1])

        message = request.form['text']
        # imgInp = request.form['imgInp']

        file = request.files['file']
        print(file)


        # create message object instance
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        #message = imgInp

        password = "mypass19@20"
        msg['From'] = "mys@gmail.com"
        msg['To'] = str(res[2].replace("'","")[:-1])
        msg['Subject'] = "New Symptom"

        # add in the message body

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

        #send pdf docs
        file_to_send = MIMEApplication(file.stream.read())
        file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file.filename)
        msg.attach(file_to_send)

        #create server
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
        server.starttls()

        # Login Credentials for sending the mail
        server.login(msg['From'], password)
        # send the message via the server.
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

        server.quit()

        success_msg = "All data have been sent to your doctor!"
        print(success_msg)
        
        return jsonify({
            'result': "Сообщение отправлено успешно",
        })
```

`html`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Information about user</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <p class="form-control" id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>
<input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add your message here"required="required">

<h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">born: </h2>
<h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">num: </h2>

<button class="btn btn-primary send">
   Send
</button>

     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

`скрипт получения данных в модальное окно`

```
<script>
function printValue(selectedItem) {
    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[{,}]/g, ''));
    console.log(selectedItem.value);
}
function process(selectedItem) {
    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
    document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
    });

 $.ajax({
    url: "/api/get_data",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        h2 = document.querySelectorAll('.white-text')
        h2[0].innerText = `born: ${data.born}`
        h2[1].innerText = `num: ${data.num}`
    },
});
}
function optionClick(selectedItem) {
    printValue(selectedItem);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Я тебе еще раз отвечаю - у тебя в чушь какая-то получается. Надо разделять api и рендеринг шаблона.Ты пытаешься функционал фронта заменить рендерингов шаблона - это неверно. Твоя проблема в непонимании разделения функционала на фронт, бэк и шаблонизатор

Comment: @cauf, можеть кто-то другой сталкивался. пусть посмотрят

Comment: Сталкивался с чем? С неверной архитектурой проекта?

Comment: @cauf, а что конкретно тут неверно? я поэтому и задал вопрос, чтобы понять где и что изменить нужно.

Comment: Блин... Ты разделил на два метода. Ок. Почему роуты одинаковые??? У тебя два обработчика на метод POST. Как ты думаешь, по какому из них будет работать твоя программа?

Comment: давай обратно [в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110551/discussion-between-cauf-and-abby). тут бесполезно эту дискуссию продолжать

Comment: @cauf, обновил код, посмотрите пожалуйста.